# write sql code to output three consecutive days which has more than 100 visitors

Tags: sql, t-sql, hive

there is a table Tourists which records the number of tourists in a place during July

```
id    date    visits
1    2017-07-01    100
……
```

the value of id is equal to the value of day in the date column, how to output dates which has more than 100 visitors in each of the following three consecutive days?

Comment: this is an interview question

Comment: And how did you attempt to solve it?

Comment: I think its date is not dependent on id column. you can simply make 'WHERE' condition .. i.e. where visitor > 100

Comment: @RashidKhan I think the id is to help identify where a condition `EXISTS` in the consecutive days

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT id,
       date_visit,
       visits
FROM   (SELECT a.*,
               COUNT(*)
                 OVER (
                   PARTITION BY rn ) cnt
        FROM   (SELECT t.*,
                       id - ROW_NUMBER()
                              OVER (
                                ORDER BY id) rn
                FROM   table1 t
                WHERE  visits > 100) a) b
WHERE  cnt >= 3
ORDER  BY id;
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, it really works, thanks, I need to look into the details

Comment: If it works for you you may upvote and mark it as the right answer. It will help others who seek answers.

Comment: I did but my reputation is low so it's not displayed

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work on your case.

```
SELECT * FROM `Tourists`
WHERE `visits` > 100
ORDER BY date [ ASC | DESC ]
LIMIT 3
```

Choose ASC or DESC as your requirements.

***let me know if i mistaken to understand your needs***

Comment: but it requires to output dates which has >100 visits in three consecutive days, not to output a single day which has >100 visits

Comment: Do you want visit counts by three days, Like a set of a week with seven days? 

Have a look on this too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3618031/6472899

Answer (score 0):

The top-voted answer is valid if we have only one sequence greater than 3. What if we have two sequence greater than 3? Then the test result will fail.

**My proposed solution in that scenario.**

```
with cte as (
select 
*,id-ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as cn
from Visitors where NO_of_visitor  >100
)
select * from cte
where cn >= (select MAX(cn) from cte)
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
WITH cte AS  
(  
        SELECT a.id AS id1, b.id AS id2, c.id AS id3  
        FROM Tourists AS a  
        INNER JOIN Tourists  AS b ON b.id= a.id+1 AND b.visits>100  
        INNER JOIN Tourists  AS c ON c.id=b.id+1 AND c.visits>100  
        WHERE a.visits >100  
)  
SELECT * FROM Tourists  WHERE Tourists.id IN (SELECT id1 FROM cte UNION SELECT id2 FROM cte UNION SELECT id3 FROM cte );
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered poor quality, hence the down-vote (and not from me). If you have not already done so, I recommend that you take the [tour] and visit the [help].